# TSQL Return Guid that occurs the most in a column

Tags: sql, t-sql

If I have a table with two columns, e.g. Name, and ID, where ID is GUID's, how do I return the Guid value from Column 2 that occurs the most?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, COUNT(*) AS CountOfRows
FROM UnknownTable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY CountOfRows DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, COUNT(ID) AS count
FROM IDTable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY count DESC
```